# Display failing to update past 46th line of code

Tags: errors, latexit

I'm a complete novice with LaTeX. Excuse the bluntness of this ignorant question which most likely has an obvious answer. On my LaTeXit, the display window fails to update past the 46th line of code. Are there any potential maladies in the code that may have caused this or am I missing some simple procedure to continue on seeing further lines of code in the display window.[image]

Comment: Welcome, you probably have an error, which wouldn't surprise me as you source code is far from expected. Did you consider reading introductory material? Or did you decide to just jump in?

Comment: LaTeXit isn't made for making large documents, it is only intended for making images of (typically) equations that can be used in e.g. Keynote or Powerpoint. Use TeXshop or TeXworks instead.

Comment: @Johannes_B I decided to just jump in.